# Application tried to present a nil model view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm currently trying to implement an introductory (tutorial) section in my application and I would like to give users the option to view it at any time. The main part of my app is made of UIViewController XIB files (`ViewController_iPhone.xib`, `ViewController_iPad.xib`) and for the purpose of my introductory views I found it easier to work with Storyboards. So in a quick summary: I am attempting to switch from the main ViewController (XIB) to the starting ViewController within the Storyboard, depending on the device type -> this all begin upon a UIButton tap.

Within my Storyboard I have assigned individual Storyboard ID's so whether it be an iPad, iPhone or iPhone-4inch, it would load the proper view:

Storyboard ID's: `3-Slide1` (iPad), `4-Slide1` (iPhone), `5-Slide1` (iPhone-4inch).

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the button code within **ViewController.m:**

```
NSString *nibName;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            nibName = @"3-Slide1";
        } else {
            if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0) {
                nibName = @"4-Slide1";
            } else {
                nibName = @"5-Slide1";
            }
        }
        
        IntroViewController *introViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:nibName];
        
        [self presentViewController:introViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**The SIGABRT Error:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target
<ViewController: 0x20865170>.
```

Why is this error appearing?

Note: there are plenty of posts with the same general SIGABRT error but all seem to have different issues.

Comment: Hang on. I just read your first paragraph again. Is it the case that the current view controller (the one with the code you've shown, from which you're trying to load this intro) was *NOT* loaded from a Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there a segue leading from your view controller to the info view controller if you are pushing it modally.

I would simply make separate segues to the view controllers (one will be in a different storyboard file, anyway), name the segues and use your logic to determine the correct segue. Then use `performSegueWithIdentifier:` rather than `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

*(I guess the nib name actually refers to the file name of a nib. Not sure, but the segue method is anyway the correct way to do this.)*

Comment: For that matter, it doesn't even seem like there should be more than one segue: iPad/iPhone would generally be in different storyboards (and could have the same segue name in each), and 3.5"/4" iPhone generally shouldn't require different target controllers, just smart layout code/constraints.

Comment: Right. If you need to simply adjust the media, you can do it in the controller...